Is it safe to hook wires from two separate circuits to one lamp?
While replacing a basement light that is on circuit #23, I discovered that three wires went into the electrical box for the light - one from the switch (circuit #23), one continuing circuit #23, and a third one from a different circuit, #25 that was still hot.
From the switch (#23): black wire was hooked to the lamp, and white was connected to the two other black wires (from #23 and #25).
Continuing circuit #23 wire: white hooked to the lamp.
Circuit #25 wire: white was also connected to the lamp.
Lamp turned off when I turned off circuit #23.
I don't know how to install the lamp now. Is this set up safe?
For context - house is from the 50s with cloth wires with no ground. We have all GFCI/AFCI breakers.

from #23 to #25 leave it alone

Another thought on this issue - I wonder if the "#25 wire" is actually part of the circuit #23 but hooked to #25 somewhere else... I tested all the switches and outlets in circuit #25, and everything is working so I didn't break the circuit... But I did cut this wire that's powered by #25

Are 23 and 25 half-size (tandem) breakers? (0V between their hots) Or are they different legs - 240V between them? Thinking possible messed up MWBC that wasn't handle-tied or some similar type of issue. Picture of the panel might help.

Are you 100% sure that breakers 23 and 25 both come to this junction box and they both carry their own live and neutral wires?  If so they should not be tied together at all.  If it was an MWBC (once) there would be one cable, one neutral, and a red wire.  So it's not that.   I suggest you unravel it, power the light from 23, disconnect 25 from everything in there, and figure out if 25 is serving anything NOW.   If not, you can disconnect it at the breaker end too, and you will have a spare breaker.  Just label everything so you know where the other end of disconnected wires are.

@DIYerInVT, How did you determine that the "#25 wire" is actually part of circuit #25? Is there any chance that your measurement picked up a phantom voltage that was induced by the wire running near circuit #25? If you leave the "#25 wire" disconnected, is there anything on circuit #23 that stopped working?

Is circuit 25 labeled at the breaker? Does it serve other fixtures?

@AdamO -   The house main two circuits are #23 and #25. #23 serves living room, hallway, and basement. #25 covers bathroom and two bedrooms. The house had an addition (kitchen) in the 80s so there are other circuits, and some circuits only serve one outlet - it's odd. Currently, #23 is off, and #25 is on. Everything on #25 is working fine.

@BartvanIngenSchenau wire is hot when #23 is off and #25 is on. Wire registers no power when #25 is off.

I haven't turned #23 back on as I have all these wires hanging from the ceiling, so I'm not sure what will work and what won't... But everything on #25 works fine.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact both #23 and #25 are standard size breakers, no half size or tandem

Do you have Romex wire? Can you not peer in to determine whether the wires are truly run in the same jacket, or are they distinctly crossed? Sometimes, such boxes are convenient locations for running passthrough splices, so circuit 25 may have nothing to do with fixtures in that room. Yet I wonder if some slapdash electrician wasn't paying attention when setting up the lamp for this location.

Hooking a single lamp up to two different circuits is not safe.
However, chances are that you misidentified which circuit(s) really provides power to each wire, given the facts that you could turn off the light by turning off a single breaker and that your GFCI breakers weren't continually tripping.
A simple test to see if the "#25 wire" is really powered by circuit #25 is to turn both circuit #25 and circuit #23 off. Then connect a lamp directly to  the "#25 wire" and switch on circuit #25 (and only that circuit). If the lamp light up, the wire is part of circuit #25. If the lamp stays off, you were measuring a phantom current and the wire is not part of circuit #25.
If the wire is not part of circuit #25, then you can proceed to install your new light and wire it up in the same way as the old light was done.
If the wire is part of circuit #25, you should find the other end of it and disconnect it there. Then cap off both ends of the wire and connect your new light only to the black of the switch wire and the white of the #23 wire (black of #23 wire goes to white of switch wire).

Add to this, (I've never tested it because it's too dangerous), but theoretically if circuit 23 is live and circuit 25 is off at the breaker, I believe you can still complete a circuit connecting hot from 23 to neutral from 25 - so a voltage read across these wires would not indicate they are part of the same circuit.
